# Learn java updates per version

Tags: java

I may be too optimistic about this. What i am looking for are the updates per version of java. To be more specific in java se 7 try-with-resources was introduced, but it was not the only thing. Is there are a documentation or tutorial from oracle website (or somewhere else which will have reliable info) where someone can find **only** the new things per version??

Comment: *Is there are a documentation* of course. They are called release notes and are usually posted on the website whenever a new version is available

Comment: Additionally, [Wikipedia's article on Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) does a pretty good job of summing up the changes each version introduced, although it's not an official source.

Comment: I presume you are looking for Release Notes. You can find them by simple google search. Secondly, why Java7? Downvoting for unclear question.

Comment: @WeareBorg My book is an old edition finishing at java se 6. So i wanted to start with java se 7 and then follow with java se 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New features can be found in the release notes.

See for example [the release notes of Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html).